# How to file a tax income for a Canadian living in the UK on the YMS visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, taxes, canada, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen currently working in the UK using the YMS Tier-5 visa. Since it is the end of the fiscal year in less than a week, I need to start thinking about filling my tax income. It used to be a lot easier when I was only working in Canada, but now, I did work as a permanent employee in Canada for half a year, and now working full-time for a different employer based in London.

What is the process to file my income tax report? If it not straightforward, where can I get support to achieve it?

Comment: Which country's tax return are you trying to do now? IIRC, you're probably going to need to do both a UK and a Canadian one for this year at least

Comment: I need to do both, but Canadian fiscal year is ending on December. I'd start with this one.

Answer (score 2):

When I moved to the UK, my accountant filed what he referred to as a "leavers" tax return which, I suppose, notifies CRA that you are no longer resident in Canada for tax purposes after a certain date. As you've moved to the UK, which has an income tax treaty with Canada, you will not have to file a further Canadian tax return after the leavers one.

I'm assuming that you have no significant assets in Canada like dividend-paying stocks, a high-interest savings account, or anything that pays you enough money to generate a T3/T4/etc slip. If you do get those, you might have to file further returns in future. You'd be best off speaking to a reputable accountant in Canada about this if you're not sure. Your run of the mill tax return shop (like H&R Block) is probably not the best place to ask as they most likely don't deal with these sorts of queries too often.

FYI, British income tax is generally covered by PAYE (pay as you earn), unless of course you've opted out or you're self-employed. As you said you're employed by someone else, it's very likely that your UK taxes are already being taken care of, so there's probably nothing at all to worry about on this end.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you forget to file the "leavers" tax return, they will eventually start asking why you haven't filed in several years. It is possible to "back-file" it and make it retroactive for the time you left, but you do have to prove that you weren't maintaining any residence in Canada. Here is the link to the "leaving Canada" form - http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/nr73/nr73-12e.pdf